# Using QTextStream to read a file that is being written to?

Tags: c++, file, qt

I currently read data from a file line by line like so

```
readFile(QFile *file)
{
    QTextStream in(file);
    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I need to extend this to handle files that are currently being written to. The `while` loop should only exit if nothing has been written to the file for N seconds.

This should be easily implemented by adding in a timer and a sleep/wait loop, continuously checking if we are still `atEnd()`. However, [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtextstream.html#atEnd) is not very clear whether the return value of `atEnd()` will change if new data has been appended to the file.

If I use a `QTextStream` to read from a file that is being written to, will the return value of `atEnd()` accurately reflect the change in file contents?

Comment: I think the wiser thing would be to read from a buffer in memory that is written to. The write to disk.

Comment: @ddriver - I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. I am not doing any writing to disk.

Comment: I see, then some other process is writing? You can test if the file size is reflected correctly by simply opening the file and check if its size increases after writing. It all depends on whether the file size is checked when the file is opened initially (more likely IMO) or checked on demand.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you might need to open, read, close, open again while preserving the location you've reached previously, so you can continue from there.

Comment: @CoryKlein Qt Creator has [FS watching system](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/libs/utils/filesystemwatcher.h) that you might find useful.

Comment: @elmigranto I'm aware of `QFileSystemWatcher` and it doesn't meet my needs, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the return value of atEnd() accurately reflect the change in file contents?

### Yes

You can test this by executing the following function:

```
void FileReader::_appendFileTest()
{    
    QFile file("/home/cklein/appendFile");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QTextStream in(&file);

    while(true)
    {
        while(!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = in.readLine();

            qDebug() << line;
        }
        SleepThread::msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

<sub>Code for `SleepThread` taken from [here](http://berenger.eu/blog/c-qsleep-qt-sleep-with-a-qthread/). It just exposes the protected `QThread::msleep()` function.</sub>

And while the application is running, type this in the terminal

```
~ $ echo "foo" >> appendFile
~ $ echo "bar" >> appendFile
```

You can see that without resetting or re-opening the file, the `atEnd()` function returns a `false` when the file is appended to.