# How to display HTML file in Qt application in realtime

Tags: python, html, qt, real-time, pyside2

I'm developing an application with PySide2 and I need to display the content of an HTML file which is a sort of log file, so it is continuously changing. I need to see these changes in realtime on my application.
Is there a smart and fast way to do so? Currently I'm continuously reading from the file and comparing last lines to see if there is a new line: if so I append it to the QTextEdit widget.

I thought that maybe Qt provides some functionalities to achieve this in a smarter way.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
    path = some_file.html

    with open(path) as file:
        old = file.readlines()
        try:
            last_line = old[-1]
        except IndexError:
            last_line = ''
        while streaming:
            line = file.readline()
            if line and line != last_line:
                qtext_edit.append(line)
                last_line = line
```

Comment: [QFileSystemWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) can be used to watch for changes to files/folders. Does that help?

Comment: @JarMan Do you mean by calling qtext_edit.setHtml(path) everytime the file has changed?

Comment: I'm only suggesting that comparing one text line to the previous is not necessarily the best way to know if there is new data in the file. QFileSystemWatcher can notify you when the contents have changed through a signal. But if it requires you to then reload the entire file, that doesn't sound optimal. I'm not sure about that. Just offering the idea.

Comment: @JarMan I got it. Unfortunately I have to append a new line everytime there is one. I was just searching a way to display an HTML file as it was displayed in a browser and keeping it updated. Anyway, your suggestion might help to reduce the calls of `line = file.readline()` and the if-condition that follows. Thanks

Comment: You can use a combination of `QTextStream` and `QFileSystemWatcher` (comment by @JarMan). For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18089094/6216474). You could use a criteria like: if the file hasn't changed in `nMinutes` then break the outer loop. When my need arises in a few months and I try it, I will post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I came out with a solution that fits my needs.

As suggested in the comments, the best way could have been to exploit `QFileSystemWatcher` to trigger a signal every time the file is changed by using the `fileChanged` signal. The problem, in my case, is that the `fileChanged` signal is not triggered continuously as I expected (the file is being continuously written) and so the `QTextEdit` doesn't update as I expect.

Therefore the possible best solution has been discarded.

I decided to re-visit my old function and try to optimize it.
Here's the code:

```
DATALOG_UPDATE_TIME = 0.1

class DatalogSignals(QObject):
    output = Signal(list)


class DatalogStreamer(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, streaming: bool, datalog: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.streaming = streaming
        self.datalog = datalog
        self.signals = DatalogSignals()

    def run(self):
        with open(self.datalog) as file:
            file.readlines()
            while self.streaming:
                time.sleep(DATALOG_UPDATE_TIME)
                lines = file.readlines()
                if lines:
                    self.signals.output.emit(lines)
        LOG.debug('Datalog streaming finished')

    def stop(self):
        self.streaming = False
```

***Note**: the code I posted in the Question was in the `run()` function of `QRunnable` as well, but I didn't post it to make it easier to understand. Now I'm posting it integrally because I think that full code could be helpful to someone.*

As you can notice, I exploited a feature of `readlines()`: after the first call, it starts to read from the **last line** it read. This means that if you called this function once, the second time you call `readlines()` (keeping the file opened) and the file didn't change, you'd get an empty list; whereas if the file changed, you would get a list with just the new lines and not all the file lines.

An object of the class `DatalogStreamer` is created in the main class and started in a `QThreadPool` (in order to not execute the code in the main thread and therefore not block the GUI). This is the method to start the streaming:

```
def _start_datalog_streaming(self):
    self.datalog_streamer = DatalogStreamer(not self.actionDisable.isChecked(), self.datalog_path)
    self.datalog_streamer.signals.output.connect(self.datalog_editor.update_datalog)
    self.thread_pool.start(self.datalog_streamer)
```

As you can see the `output` signal (the one that emits the new lines) is connected to method of the object `datalog_editor` (class `DatalogEdit`, which is nothing but a subclass of `QTextEdit`).
Here's the method's implementation:

```
def update_datalog(self, lines):
    self.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
    for line in lines:
        self.insertHtml(line.replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") + "<br>")
    self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
```

I used `insertHtml()` because *lines* (list of strings) can contain *html tags*. Moreover, I replaced "\t" with 4 spaces (* *) as it was ignored and add a newline after every line (*
*).

With this simple solution I have a solved three problems:

- same subsequent lines were not printed (just the first) whereas now they all get printed
- text in `QTextEdit` is now formatted as the one in the HTML file
- the reading from file "sampling time" is increased from *undefined* (very small time) to 0.1s reducing computational effort